# How to change the background color for tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
    $("a").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().match('UP'); 
        }).click(function() {
        $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        var num = 1;
        $('tr').eq(num).toggleClass('highlight');
    });
```

What I want to do is that when I click on my link UP my default tr is to change back to his original color and the tr above change to the yellow color.
This is what i have right now:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a sample that I hope does what you want. It have to be improved a bit, but it will do the trick :)

```js
$(function() {
          $('#up').on('click', function(){
              var row = $('tr.highlight');
              row.prev().addClass('highlight');
              row.removeClass('highlight');
          });
          $('#down').on('click', function(){
             var row = $('tr.highlight');
              row.next().addClass('highlight');
              row.removeClass('highlight');
          });      
        });
```

```css
    tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
    tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
    tr.highlight{
      background: yellow !important;
    }
    tr:hover{
      background: #FF0000;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <h2>2: Zebra Striping Demo</h2>
        <table width="200" border="1" id = "changes">
            <caption>
                <a href="#" id="up">UP</a>
                Zebra Striping Demo <a href="#" id="down">DN</a>
            </caption>
            <thead>
              <tr> 
                    <th>January</th>
                    <th>February</th>
                    <th>March</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                <tr class = "highlight">
                    <td>April</td>
                    <td>May</td>
                    <td>June</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>July</td>
                    <td>August</td>
                    <td>September</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>October</td>
                    <td>November</td>
                    <td>December</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Monday</td>
                    <td>Tuesday</td>
                    <td>Wednesday</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Thursday</td>
                    <td>Friday</td>
                    <td>Saturday</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Spring</td>
                    <td>Summer</td>
                    <td>Fall</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
```